Gatling 3.11. ClosedEnjectionStep for less than 1 rps
I want to start my scenario from 10 requests per minute with the closed model. This is 0.16 RPS. Than I want to increase request count via incrementConcurrentUsers method. But there is no ability to setup closed profile with values less then 1:
scenario.injectClosed(
    constantConcurrentUsers(1) // integer argument
)

With the open profile i can do it:
scenario.injectOpen(
    constantUsersPerSec(0.16)
)

How to implement load test from 0.16 to 1 rps with Closed model?

see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403812/gatling-scenario-with-10-requests-per-hour-less-that-1-rps

This is for open model, I am searching for the closed.
